# Another instance of exe opened when running procces task, where to search the problem?

Tags: python, compilation, instance, vmware, cx-freeze

After compiling Python project (on vmvare windows) into an EXE file using cx_Freeze and testing it on VMware, actions that require processes (proccesing ics - calendar file records) another instance of the app (exe) launched. What could be causing this? When runiing the project on vmware from python it works.

Is it vmware problem or cx_freeze? Somebody stuck on this problem?

Run program on mac from python - works
Run program on VMVare windows - works
Compile to exe using cx_freeze on wmvare
run exe on vmware - app works mostly, but when doing

```
    def read_file(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            ics_text = file.read()
        return ics_text
    
    def put_calendar_grid_data_in_q(file_path, q : Queue):
    ics_text = read_file(file_path)
    p = Process(target=parse_file, args=(ics_text, q,))
    p.start()
```

somewhere here just another copy of app is oppened.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it,

added freeze support in main.py

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
freeze_support()
```